# Combined preincrement and postincrement in C

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

This is an ugly code used only to terrorize job applicants during interviews...
But I cannot understand the logic behind it.
Can someone explain why the expression with "b" is not equal to the one with "a"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
    printf("%d %d %d", ++a + a++ + 1, 1 + ++b + b++, ++c + c++); // displays 6 5 5
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this actually valid? Doesn't it violate the restriction against reading and modifying the same value multiple times between sequence points?

Comment: The only thing that question will tell you about an applicant is that if he/she gets up and walks out of the interview, that was the person you should have hired.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behavior and is (I assume) mostly in the interview to check if the user has the guts to say they don't know (or know it's undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

This is a slightly different, yet similar example (thanks Zan):

2) Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.

C++ example:

```
std::printf("%d %d", i,++i); // invokes Undefined Behaviour because of Rule no 2
```

Comment: small difference there in that your example uses `i` in two different function parameters. the question uses a single variable in each parameter.

Comment: @ZanLynx Oh whoops, you're right.  The thread is a good read regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is simple:

Create **Undefined Behavior** and let the nasal demons terrorise the job applicant. That is known as job security.

If you write to a variable, you must not access it again without intervening sequence point except to calculate the value which shall be written.

There's a second case of UB or at least *Implementation Defined Behavior*:

```
void main()
```

Should be one of

```
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: Did C++11 change those rules? I need to go look that up now. I suspect that operator overloading and native operators got all clarified and stuff.

Comment: @ZanLynx: They followed C and moved from sequence points to sequenced before/after/indeterminately/not, though without changing sematics.

Comment: Something like that. I believe that in all versions of C++ if a user defined class was used instead of int, this would be fully defined, and in C++11 it would be fully defined with int.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Lucky thing he never used the same variable for two arguments.

Comment: @Zan - yes, the sequencing rules change in C++11 and some things that were undefined in C++98 are now well-defined in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Just to prove that this is a terrible idea, here's the output in VS2012 (technically C++ compiler I suppose):

`5 5 4`

GCC & G++:

`6 5 5`

So apparently your interviewer tried it in GCC.

Comment: Yes, it was compiled with GCC.

Comment: Interesting because on my copy of GCC 4.6.3 (Ubuntu 12.04) it is 5 5 4. With any level of optimization the code turns into straight register loads of 5 5 4 and a print.

Comment: GCC 4.1.2 does the same 5 5 4. Where'd you get a 6 5 5?

Comment: I get 6 5 5 with gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)